# Bluetooth and Android on Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, bluetooth, android

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3+ with Stretch installed and updated.  I'm trying to connect my Android phone to send and receive commands.  After reading hundreds of articles about Bluetooth and Raspi without a solution on Stretch, I'm here to ask how it works.  I can connect the devices but I don't get an rfcomm device.  The serial protocol is activated.  When I pair the devices over the GUI, I get the following error:

```
Connetion failed-GDBus.Error.org.bluez Error.Failed: Protocol not available. Try to connect manually
```

I thought that the serial protocol is missing, but also after activating it and reboot, I get the same error.

Any hints on what to do here?

Comment: I have made a little progress here.  
After reinstalling Raspian, activating the Serial Profile and pairing the phone (Moto G5) the connection information on the GUI of the Raspi remains green.

Comment: But there is still no RFComm device, nor can I get a connect with the serial Bluetooth terminal. When I try to connect it says: read failed, socket might closed or timeout.